Second largest eigenvalue of graph
Let $G$ be a connected $d$-regular n-vertex graph and let $k:= k(n)\in \mathbb{N}.$ Given a Non-empty set of vertices $\phi\neq B\subseteq V(G),$ how can I prove that all but at most $\frac{\lambda_2|B|}{(k-\frac{d}{n}|B|)^2}$ vertices $v\in V(G)$ satisfy $deg_{G}(v,B):=|\{b\in B: vb\in E(G)\}|\leq k,\lambda_2$ is the second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of $G?$
